# Where can I find tables of the refractive index (real and complex part) or dielectric function as a function of frequency for different materials?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, resource-recommendations, refraction, dielectric

I need this information to do simulations for my master's thesis but I don't know if there is a bibliography or a repository on the internet with this information. They are simple materials, water, air, carbon, and things like that.

Comment: If there's a specific wavelength (or energy or frequency) range it might be easier find what you need quickly. We can find information from near-DC to microwaves to infrared-vis-UV to X-ray and gamma rays. Sometimes it will be given as [complex index of refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) $n + ik$ and sometimes [complex permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity#Complex_permittivity) $\epsilon^{\prime} +i \epsilon^{\prime \prime}$

Comment: For more about that see [Converting a complex index of refraction to a complex dielectric constant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397483/83380)

Comment: https://refractiveindex.info/

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are the [Sellmeier equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sellmeier_equation). Obviously, there are numerous materials. Best is to search the literature for the Sellmeier equations of the specific materials that you are interested in.

Comment: These are incredibly useful especially in wavelength/frequency/energy ranges where the medium is transparent or weakly absorbing and an approximate value is all that's necessary. But for more accurate values, or ranges closer to absorption edges where materials start to be strongly absorbing one should not be looking for Sellmeier equations. Instead, if you need a smooth analytical function rather than interpolating a table there are all kinds of oscillator and Drude dispersion models based on coefficients. With parameterizations, *[caveat emptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor)*